# Microsoft Edge doesn't open pages via 'microsoft-edge:' protocol and NetBIOS name as a hostname

Tags: browser, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to start Edge from command line, using `'microsoft-edge:'` protocol, e.g. typing in cmd.exe or PowerShell `"start microsoft-edge:http://microsoft.com"`. It works perfectly is most cases, but not when I use NetBIOS name (network name of computer in domain or workgroup) for a hostname, e.g.  `"start microsoft-edge:http://WIN-12345678:1337"` for local machine or `"start microsoft-edge:http://MyCompanyIntranetServer"`.

I have two VMWare Player 7 virtual machines with 32-bit and 64-bit builds of Windows 10240, and VirtualBox 5.0 with 32-bit build of 10240, and in both configurations when I first execute such a command, it works. Next attempts do not work at all (new browser tab doesn't open, nothing happens). Also  I can not open any new tabafter command execution, close any tab or close browser at all.

Also, this doesn't happen when I use IP-address, or 'localhost' on local machine, e.g. `"start microsoft-edge:http://localhost:1337"` or `"start microsoft-edge:http://10.0.0.5"` can be executed successfully number of times; or when I use Edge as a default browser and omit 'microsoft-edge:' protocol, e.g. `"start http://WIN-12345678:1337"` or `"start http://MyCompanyIntranetServer"`.

Looks like it's a bug in Edge, or maybe VM or network environment issue, or something different; is there anyone who knows something about it?